# Sybase Database Support on Node.js with SSL

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-asa, sybase-ase15, sybase-rs

I am working on this project that has been bugging me for a while and wanted to ask community's help on it. So basically we have an On-Prem Sybase database that needs to communicate with a cloud micro service running in Kubernetes in AWS. I am currently building this micro service in Node.js and have tried to communicate with the db using sybase module or node-sybase module. Both of these module seems to use the Java Jar Linker to communicate with the database when I reviewed the node_modules. I was able to make the connection without the SSL but not sure how to make the SSL connection work. Do I have to create my own Custom Jar here or what is the process. If anyone has resolved this error please let me know.